# How do I reduce to a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing some computation with symbols `X, Y, Z, XX, XY, ...`, which are linearly independent elements in some larger vector space. For example, consider the following simple set:

```
set = {X, Y, X + Y, X + Z, 2 X + Z}
```

I would like to obtain a basis of the subspace `V = Span(set)` so that this basis is a subset of `Set` obtained by going through the list and removing those elements that are linear combinations of those that we already picked. The output for this simple example should by `{X, Y, X + Z}`.

Is there a quick way of doing this simply by converting to vectors, finding a basis, and converting the answer back to `set` elements?

Edit 1. The set above is just an example. In my computations it can have 100s of elements.

Comment: `GroebnerBasis[{x, y, x + y, x + z, 2*x + z}, {x, y, z}]` produces an equivalent basis `{z, y, x}`.

Comment: Thanks but I really want a subset of Set.

Comment: `Set` is a protected system symbol. Generally most users avoid using capitals to start their own symbol and function names.

Comment: Thanks Michael E2. changed Set -> set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the things I remember from my linear algebra class in 1983:

```
set = {X, Y, X + Y, X + Z, 2 X + Z};

Extract[set, 
 FirstPosition[#, 1, Nothing] & /@ 
  RowReduce@Transpose@CoefficientArrays[set, Variables@set][[2]]
 ]

(*  {X, Y, X + Z}  *)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user76928 You're welcome! :)

Comment: Can this be generalized to the case where the elements of set are matrices or even tensors of variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, for `set = {X, Y, X + Y, X + Z, 2 X + Z, Z^2};` your code performs `{X,Y,X+Z}`

Comment: @user64494 Unfortunately for your example, `Z^2` seems to be nonsense according to the question.

Comment: @user64494 `X`, `Y`, `Z` are supposed to be vectors in a vector space, not variables in a polynomial ring

Comment: @Hausdorff If so, then what is `XX`?

Comment: @Hausdorff: Thank you. I repeat my question: what is `XX`?

Comment: @Hausdorff: `X^2` also can be treated as a symbol, isn't so?

Comment: @MichaelE2: Why do you think so? You may replace `X^2` by `T^2` with the same result.

Comment: @user64494 The square of a vector in a vector space is undefined.  Only (homogeneous) linear combinations of the variables are permitted.

Comment: @MichaelE2: `T^2` in `set = {X, Y, X + Y, X + Z, 2 X + Z, T^2` is treated as a symbol. Hope I'm clear. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @user64494 `Head[T^2]` is not `Symbol`. If it is your desire to treat `T^2` as a symbol, that is a separate question and has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Agreed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are just working with vectors, you can use `RowReduce` to remove linearly dependent elements in `set`.

Taking your example,

```
set = {X, Y, X + Y, X + Z, 2 X + Z}
```

you can, assuming `X`, `Y` and `Z` are some vectors in a vector space, define associated vectors via

```
setVecs = set /. {X -> {1, 0, 0}, Y -> {0, 1, 0}, Z -> {0, 0, 1}}
```

**Edit**: As suggested in the comments, this can be automated, e.g. via

```
 setVecs = set /. With[{vars = Variables[set]}, 
      MapIndexed[Rule[#1, UnitVector[Length@vars, First@#2]] &, vars]]
```

Since

```
MatrixRank[setVecs]
```

> ```
>  3
> ```

we need to remove two elements. Which ones to remove can be found by looking at the pivots of

```
rr = setVecs // Transpose // RowReduce
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
>  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

The third element is therefore a linear combination of the first two, and the fifth element is the sum off the first and fourth element of `set`. To get the basis element positions in `set` we can use

```
basisElements = Flatten[FirstPosition[#, 1, Nothing] & /@ rr]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4}
> ```

The associated elements of `set` can then be extracted via

```
basis = set[[basisElements]]]
```

> ```
> {X, Y, X + Z}
> ```

Comment: That is done by hand with help of Mathematica. Think of higher dimensions, say 1024.

Comment: But I have no control what's in Sets (an output of some computation). It can have 100s of elements.

Comment: That should not be a problem, collect all variables `X`, `Y`, `Z`, etc., replace them with some basis vectors, and the steps after that should work exactly the same

Comment: The approach in this answer can be generalized with something like `set /. With[{vars = Variables[set]}, Thread[vars -> IdentityMatrix[Length[vars]]]]`.

Comment: `UnitVector[k]` could also be used.

Comment: @J.M.'s ennui. Thanks, `Variables[set]` is very useful.